# React animation not working when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, react-hooks

I have this component which is generating a new random number on click of the start button, I want it to create a fade-in effect every time the new number is rendered in the text element, but for some reason, the animation is not working, can you please have a look at it, I am learning React Native.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Animated } from 'react-native';

const BoxWithRandomNumber = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true, // Add this line for better performance
      }
    ).start();
  }, [number]);

  const generateRandom = () => {
    let c = 0;
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
      if (++c === 5) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
    }, 1500)
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>  
        <Animated.Text style={{ fontSize: 36, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#ecf0f1',opacity: fadeAnim, }}>
          {number}
        </Animated.Text>
      <Button title="Start" onPress={generateRandom} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default BoxWithRandomNumber;
```

I have even put the number variable as a dependency array, to my knowledge, the use effect should work whenever there is a change in the value I provided. but it's not working, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing is to set the value to 0 before you run the animation again. The animation is running, but since the value is already 1, the change isn't visible.

Try adding `fadeAnim.setValue(0)` to the useEffect before you call `Animated.timing`.  You can find more about this in the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvalue).